# Limit of dialogs in Einstein bot

Tags: limits, einstein, bots

Is there a limit on number of dialogs in Einstein Bot?

When I added more then 100, next one don't show up in dialog search, but I believe they are there, because I can not create new one with same name. The problem is I can't access them ;/

Does some know anything?

Answer (score 0):

Technically they are still there, but the only way to see them is to export the metadata. From the `.bot` xml tree, I was able to manually move the dialog nodes up. After re-deploying/saving the `.bot` files, I could view them again in the Einstein Bot builder.

Answer (score 0):

[Einstein Bots System Limitations](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.bots_service_limitations.htm&type=5) covers this:

- Apex calls before an outbound message    50
- Active bots per org  20
- Conditions per step  5
- **Dialog groups per bot version: 100**
- **Dialogs per bot version:   500**
- Entities per intent set (domain) 500
- Fields selected for each lookup  10
- Intent extensions per intent 20
- Intents per intent set (domain)  2000
- Items for the Bot Options menu   5
- Links to other dialogs per bot navigation    50
- Quick replies per bot variable operation 20
- Steps per dialog 50
- Steps under a group step 5
- Utterances per bot   10000
- Utterances per intent    2000
- Values for each list variable entity 200
- Variables per bot version    500
- Versions per bot 20